# string is not defined when echo text in php-js

Tags: php

I'm a very noob to PHP.

Below is my code

```
<script>
 let x = <?php echo "AB"; ?>
 console.log(x)
</script>
```

Log says that 'ABconsole is not defined'.

Is there anything else I missed??

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: "_Is there anything else I missed??_" Yes, the quotes in JS

Comment: let x = '<?php echo "AB"; ?>'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass a PHP string to a JavaScript variable (and escape newlines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines)

Comment: for you the console.log is an other instruction but not for the computer , you need an Instruction separation `;` , resultat -> `let x = <?php echo "AB"; ?> ; ` , you can remove the separator in the php, with the `?>` you are tell him your instruction is end 
so `let x = <?php echo "AB" ?> ; `

Comment: What exactly is the use of printing the string `AB` via PHP? Why not just do that in JS?

Comment: @WolfCode The missing `;` is not the problem here, it's the missing quotes. Adding `;` would still error "Uncaught ReferenceError: AB is not defined"

Comment: @brombeer Exactly what I want, it was quote problem. Adding ';' doesn't work in this problem. Also, regardless with 'encode_json' method.

Comment: @brombeer Simply printing string is not my goal. When I check php variable with js, console.log(<?php echo $var . "AB" ?>) doesn't work while console.log(<?php echo $var ?>) work. I just wanted to print pretty like console.log(<?php echo "$var : " . $var ?>).